# Acknowledgement Process. Alternative to Sites?

Tags: force.com-sites

The only solution that I can think of for following scenario is creating sites page. I was wondering if there are any other simpler/elegant solution for these kind of requirements. Thank you for your time!!

Say a football club signs a player. He is officially associated with the club, but is not allowed to enter in the training ground unless he reads and acknowledges a policy created by ground staffs.

Now what other alternatives are there to get players acknowledgement other than sending out an email(before their accounts are created) with the link to a sites page where he can navigate the policy and submit his acknowledgement?

Thank you for your insights!!

Answer (score 0):

You could also have a Web2Lead form (or Web2Anything) to create a Lead of a certain type which you could then process automatically to store acknowledgements.